# Equality of two multivariate normal CDF's

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Let $\pmb{X} \sim N_d(\pmb{\mu}, \pmb{\Sigma})$ and $\pmb{Y} \sim N_d(\pmb{\nu}, \pmb{\Omega})$; $\pmb{\mu} \neq \pmb{\nu}, \pmb{\mu} \neq \pmb{0}, \pmb{\nu} \neq \pmb{0}$, and $\pmb{\Sigma}\neq\pmb{\Omega}$. Then under what condition $P(\pmb{X}>\pmb{0}) = P(\pmb{Y}>\pmb{0})$?

Try: $P(\pmb{X}>\pmb{0}) = P(\pmb{X}-\pmb{\mu}>-\pmb{\mu}) = P[\pmb{\Sigma}^{-1/2}(\pmb{X}-\pmb{\mu})>-\pmb{\Sigma}^{-1/2}\pmb{\mu}] = \Phi(\pmb{\Sigma}^{-1/2}\pmb{\mu})$. Similarly, $P(\pmb{Y}>\pmb{0}) = \Phi(\pmb{\Omega}^{-1/2}\pmb{\nu})$. Thus, when $\pmb{\Sigma}^{-1/2}\pmb{\mu} =\pmb{\Omega}^{-1/2}\pmb{\nu} $.

But, later I noticed that $P(\pmb{X}-\pmb{\mu}>-\pmb{\mu})$ is not necessarily equal to  $P[\pmb{\Sigma}^{-1/2}(\pmb{X}-\pmb{\mu})>-\pmb{\Sigma}^{-1/2}\pmb{\mu}]$.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  After all, your condition imposes a single (differentiable) constraint on the $2d + d(d+1)$ parameters and therefore defines a $d^2+3d-1$-dimensional manifold of solutions.

Comment: I want a condition between the parameters of $\pmb{X}$, $\{\pmb{\mu}, \pmb{\Sigma}\}$, and the parameters of $\pmb{Y}$, $\{\pmb{\nu}, \pmb{\Omega}\}$ so that the equality $P(\pmb{X}>\pmb{0})= P(\pmb{Y}>\pmb{0})$ holds. A similar kind of condition with that I have tried. e.g, for the univariate case, the condition would be $\mu/\sigma = \nu/\omega$.

Comment: You've given a condition already.  Ordinarily, the other way to specify a manifold that is defined by an implicit equation is to parameterize it--which would involve $d^2+3d-1$ parameters.  That doesn't look likely to be at all simple, to be available in closed form, or even to be useful.  Could you perhaps explain the problem that motivated this question?